# Difference between QJsonValue and QVariant?

Tags: c++, qt, types, qvariant

I'm working with Qt and JSON. Now, I have two options: `QVariant` and `QJsonValue`. I don't get the point in which they are different?

I know QVariant has some more methods and `QJsonValue` has the is*** methods(where `QVariant` has type).
But is there any other main difference (maybe speed)? If no: Why are there two classes which can do nearly the same?

Comment: of course, Qvariant can contain more types, but why should I use QJsonvalue if there is the alternative QVariant?

Comment: JsonValue is a specialized type that only allows certain types of data indicated in the standard json as strings, numbers, booleans, etc.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now. QJsonvalue is not that different from QVariant, but it has some small advantages. Like you said... just JSON Values inside. And what I found out right before, QJsonvalue are strictly typed -> you can't do any implicit conversions.    Thanks for helping @eyllanesc

Comment: Everything mentioned above is true and aside from that you can store some Qt-specific types in QVariant or register your own and store it. They may not be easily serializable to Json but could be stored in QVariant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**QVariant** give you more flexibility in manipulating data.